# Matlab optimization using genetic algorithm

Tags: matlab, optimization

I want to fit a curve from a theoretical model to experimental data points. The model consists of 5 parameters. I can easily get the closest fit but I want something different. I need the closest fit possible but it should never go below the experimental curve. In other words, every y-value of the fit should be greater than or equal to the corresponding y-value from the experiment.
I would highly appreciate any ideas on how this could be implemented. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding nonlinear constraints to your genetic algorithm?

More details are given here
https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/examples/constrained-minimization-using-the-genetic-algorithm.html

In your case all you would need to do would be

assign 
the 'c' inequality constraint value in your non-linear constraints function 
to the difference between the new y values and the actual y values and the genetic algorithm should do the rest.